# OpenCV - Calculating the correct coordinates using homography matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, matrix, homography

Given a homography matrix H (3x3), how can I find the right coordinate (x,y) in the transformed image? I understand in openCV I can use

```
    perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);
```

where obj_corners are the coordinates in the original image, scene_corners are the coordinates in the result image. And I thought the computation formula should be:

```
    w = H_31 * obj_corners[i].x + H_32 * obj_corners[i].y + H_33 * 1;
    scene_corners[i].x = (H_11 * obj_corners[i].x + H_12 * obj_corners[i].y + H_13 * 1) / w;
    scene_corners[i].y = (H_21 * obj_corners[i].x + H_22 * obj_corners[i].y + H_23 * 1) / w;
```

Now I have a transform matrix H as H=[95, 41, 246; 51, 160, 8; 240, 63, 240]. If my obj_corner is (0,0), using the above equation, the scene_corner should be (246/240, 8/240). However, when I use openCV perspectiveTransform() function, the scene_corner is (17.56, -12.98). Why there is a mis-match here?

I got this transforma matrix H from cv::findHomography() function. And I know the answer of (0,0) --> (17.56, -12.98) is correct. I just don't know how to calculate this coordinate. Especially how to get a negative number here.

To be more clearly, here is how I my openCV code look like with a wrong output:

```
    cv::Mat H = cv::findHomography(trackedPoints2, trackedPoints1, CV_RANSAC);
    double H11 = H.data[0];
    double H12 = H.data[1];
    double H13 = H.data[2];
    double H21 = H.data[3];
    double H22 = H.data[4];
    double H23 = H.data[5];
    double H31 = H.data[6];
    double H32 = H.data[7];
    double H33 = H.data[8];
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int w = H31 * x + H32 * y + H33;
    double x_dst = ((H11 * x + H12 * y + H13) + w / 2) / w;
    double y_dst = ((H21 * x + H22 * y + H23) + w / 2) / w;
```

And here is the openCV code gives correct answer (17.56, -12.98)

```
    cv::Mat H = cv::findHomography(trackedPoints2, trackedPoints1, CV_RANSAC);
    std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(1);
    obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0, 0);
    std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(1);
    perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);
    printf("%f, %f\n", scene_corners[0].x, scene_corners[0].y);
```

Can someone give a hint on what is wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, it will be hard to get negative values for the transform of x,y=0,0 if all the coefficients of the matrix describing the homography are positive ! Take a look at the file `opencv2.4-8/modules/core/src/matmult.cpp` to see how `perpectiveTransform()` is implemented. It is really close to your code, except for the `+w/2`. Moreover, since `w` is typed as int, w/2 is an integer division and there is an implicit cast of `H31*x+...` to int : something may be wrong there ! But fixing this will not help getting negative values...

Comment: Hi Francis, thanks for your reply. Yes, the w/2 part is not so correct. It was written before as a round effect when I define x_dst and y_dst as 'int'. It will give +0.5 to both values in current 'double' implementation. However, as you said, I have no clue how can I get the correct answer with negative value with this homography matrix.